# xorg - запуск на смартфоне с Android

Tags: android, linux, xorg

Пытаюсь запустить xorg на смартфоне с Android, через терминал в TWRP делаю chroot в папку с файловой системой от Debian - это отлично работает, установил туда xorg и xfce4.

Но при попытка старта (startx) - получаю ошибку, что /dev/tty0 не существует.
Насколько я понял, в Android - tty находится по пути /dev/pts/ (например /dev/pts/0)

Как можно решить данную проблему?

P.S. Пробывал создавать ссылку от /dev/pts/0 в /dev/tty0 (смотрите скриншот)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X требует эксклюзивного доступа к консоли, а она занята андроидом, и подключения драйвера икса к драйверу видеокарты, которая тоже занята андроидом. Для запуска второй консоли в андроиде нужно его модифицировать.

Для того чтоб получить картинку из чрута используйте XVnc или XSpice. Подключитесь програмкой и увидете окошки программы.

/dev/pts/* это не консоль, а виртуальный терминал.

Перед chroot сделай бинд основных папок:

```
mount -B /dev /linux_chroot/dev
mount -B /sys /linux_chroot/sys
mount -B /proc /linux_chroot/proc
chroot /linux_chroot /bin/bash
```

`mount -o bind /dev /linux_chroot/dev` если нет флага `-B`

Также консоль можно подключить их через mknod

```
mknod /dev/tty c 5 0
mknod /dev/tty0 c 4 0
mknod /dev/tty1 c 4 1
```

Но этого будет не достаточно - чтоб создать все устройства запусти `udev`, а ещё лучше `/sbin/init` (после udev, если твой инит не systemd)

Comment: Androd не запущен на моменте включеного TWRP. За /dev/tps/* понял

Comment: @kotleni дополнил

Comment: udev, не нашел как правило создавать для /dev/tty0

Comment: @kotleni mknod из ответа